# Beginner Discrete Math Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm doing review questions from a textbook, and there's one that goes like this:

"The disjunction of two contingencies can be a tautology."

The way I see it is this: Let $x$ and $y$ be two propositions. Let $T(x)$ mean $x$ is a tautology. Let $C(x)$ mean $x$ is a contradiction. For some of these $x$ and $y$, they are both contingencies (aka they are neither tautologies nor contradictions, or $\neg(T(x)∨C(x))$, and their disjunction is a tautology $(T(x) \text{ and } T(y))$, or:

$$\exists x, \exists y\,(\neg(T(x)\vee C(x))\wedge\neg(T(y)\vee C(y))\wedge T(x)\wedge T(y)),$$ which simplifies to $$\exists x, \exists y\,(\neg T(x)\wedge\neg C(x)\wedge \neg T(y)\wedge\neg C(y)\wedge T(x\wedge y)).$$

However, the book disagrees, telling me that the answer is:
$$\exists x\exists y(\ T(x)\wedge\neg C(x)\wedge\neg T(y)\wedge\neg C(y)\wedge T(x\vee y)).$$
Now I might just be splitting hairs here, but why is the tautology an "or" statement if we're saying that the disjunction of both $x$ **and** $y$ result in a tautology?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the book's question that you are trying to answer, exactly?

Comment: Actually I understand what I did now. The book was asking me to translate the English phrase to a logic statement. The or statement is inherent in the "disjunction" part of the premise, I just misread it.